# Using pre-shared key from ESP32 to a Spring boot secure API

Tags: java, spring-boot, esp32

I am trying to send some data from an ESP32 device to a secure spring boot API.
I am trying with a simple WiFiClientPSK.ino sketch which is available on Github [WiFiClientPSK](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFiClientSecure/examples/WiFiClientPSK/WiFiClientPSK.ino)

It is using
client.setPreSharedKey(pskIdent, psKey);
to set the pre-share key

On the server side, I have setup the spring boot application to accept SSL connection and I am trying to get the PSK in the header.
Below is the code

```
@RestController
public class WebController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/", method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
    public String check(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) {
        System.out.println("Header = "+headers.toString());
        return "";
    }
}
```

This is the SSL config

```
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:springboot.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-alias=springboot
server.port=8443
```

when I try to make the connection from the SPE32 after installing the sketch in the DEVKIT, I get this error on the serial monitor

```
11:58:59.169 -> Starting connection to server...
11:58:59.169 -> [V][WiFiClientSecure.cpp:146] connect(): start_ssl_client with PSK
11:58:59.169 -> [V][ssl_client.cpp:59] start_ssl_client(): Free internal heap before TLS 280500
11:58:59.169 -> [V][ssl_client.cpp:65] start_ssl_client(): Starting socket
11:58:59.342 -> [V][ssl_client.cpp:141] start_ssl_client(): Seeding the random number generator
11:58:59.342 -> [V][ssl_client.cpp:150] start_ssl_client(): Setting up the SSL/TLS structure...
11:58:59.342 -> [V][ssl_client.cpp:178] start_ssl_client(): Setting up PSK
11:58:59.377 -> [V][ssl_client.cpp:234] start_ssl_client(): Setting hostname for TLS session...
11:58:59.377 -> [V][ssl_client.cpp:249] start_ssl_client(): Performing the SSL/TLS handshake...
11:58:59.583 -> [E][ssl_client.cpp:36] _handle_error(): [start_ssl_client():253]: (-30336) SSL - No CA Chain is set, but required to operate
11:58:59.583 -> [E][WiFiClientSecure.cpp:153] connect(): start_ssl_client: -30336
11:58:59.583 -> [V][ssl_client.cpp:302] stop_ssl_socket(): Cleaning SSL connection.
11:58:59.583 -> Connection failed!
```

And on the spring boot application I don't get any traffic.
Has anyone done that before or any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: It seems Spring might also need your CA in its trustore (config file: server.ssl.trust-store:pathToTrustore)

Comment: I'm not seeing anything on the server side at all, `SSL - No CA Chain is set, but required to operate` this error is displayed on the ESP32 device when it is trying to initiate the connection.

Comment: Have you tried a simple ping from the device? Just to be sure it detects your SpringApp